# How to force Actionbar tabs to align below Actionbar?

Tags: android, android-actionbar, android-tabs

I have used SupportActionBar with 5 tabs (icons without title just like facebook). When I run the application with minSdkVersion:16, tabs are aligning below Actionbar as expected. But, when I run it with minSdkVersion:14 tabs are aligning on actionbar. 
How do I force the tabs to align below actionbar. ?

Code:

```
        // oncreate

        actionBar = getSupportActionBar();
        actionBar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_TABS);  
        actionBar.setTitle(getHomePageTitle(0));

        mViewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager_exp); 
        mViewPager.setAdapter(mSectionsPagerAdapter);



        // For each of the sections in the app, add a tab to the action bar.
        for (int i = 0; i < mSectionsPagerAdapter.getCount(); i++) 
        {

                Tab tab = getSupportActionBar().newTab(); 
                tab.setCustomView(R.layout.badgemenuitem);

                icon  = (ImageView)tab.getCustomView().findViewById(R.id.img_tabs_badge); 

                actionBar.addTab(tab    
                        .setIcon(null)  
                        .setTabListener(this));  

            switch (i) 
            {
                case 0:

                    icon.setImageResource(R.drawable.a);

                    break;

                case 1: 
                    icon.setImageResource(R.drawable.b);

                    break;

                case 2:
                    icon.setImageResource(R.drawable.c);

                    break;

                case 3:
                    icon.setImageResource(R.drawable.d);

                    break;

                case 4:
                    icon.setImageResource(R.drawable.e);

                    break; 


            }

        }
```

Comment: are you working on landscape mode?

Comment: @BSKANIA No I'm using it in Portrait mode only

Comment: @Anirudh post the code for adding the tabs